# Remove paddingTop in UICollectionView Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, uicollectionview, uiedgeinsets

I am developing an iOS app using Xamarin.iOS . I have used `UICollectionView` to display a list of categories. I have used `StoryBoard` to design the interface. I have one problem:

`CollectionView` has a `padding` from the top. As far as I got it has to do with `insets`. I have used `UIEdgeInsets` but no success. Is there any option how to remove that space/padding from the top. The `collectionView` is used with other layouts so I need to remove it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove padding from the top of UICollectionView Xamarin.iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36595755/remove-padding-from-the-top-of-uicollectionview-xamarin-ios)

Comment: You asked this same question **2 hours** ago!!  Please don't post duplicates!

Comment: I thought I had deleted the first one. Let me check once again.

Comment: Why did you delete it? you can edit the question if you need to make changes.